# Possible to use G-Suite services & Personal Email Server on the same domain?

Tags: email, email-server, g-suite

Is it possible for me to share email services. What I want to do in the name of saving money is. Have a email server using MailCow for example, as a fall back to my Google Provided services. Only a few people in my company need Google's suite of tools, everyone else just needs the @example.com.

Problem being is, we can't get email sent to users of the MailCow server. Google Bounces the emails back and unable to send. I've tried changing the MX records to point to our server all mail gets received in that scenario. So the server is working. But No matter where we place the weight value of the MX for our server once google is in the mix of MX records, we can't get mail to one or the other service.

I know this has to be possible I am just no sure how. Do I have to bind the domain and manage dns on my server to make this work? or can I do this all through the DNS management of my registrar? I ask cause I am sure this has to be DNS related somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is absolutely possible with [dual delivery](https://support.google.com/a/answer/96855?hl=en).  You do not change your mx records, Google will send all email to both endpoints.

I've personally done this with gsuite, o365 and premise exchange, all working in tandem. (sent mail not sync but inbound is)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have two incoming MailHosts (aka MX records) for a given domain.

You have to choose either G Suite *or* another System.

It is possible though, to put a new MTA (as the primary MX target) in front of both systems, that distributes each and every message to both targets. But this will led you to *a lot* of other problems (Spam fighting, PointOfFailure, added complexity ...), so consider that very careful.